# How can I modify a function that draws vertical lines using SFML to automatically space them out?

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm working on a sorting algorithm visualizer project using SFML. I created a vector of `sf::RectangleShape`  objects representing the vertical lines to be sorted.

```
std::vector <sf::RectangleShape> lineVector;
int xpos = 100;

int N;
std::cout << "Enter the size of the vector to be sorted: ";
std::cin >> N;

srand(time(0));

for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    int randomNum = rand() % N + 1;
    sf::RectangleShape line = plot(randomNum, xpos, 200);
    lineVector.push_back(line);
    xpos += 5;
}
```

I use `rand` to generate a random number from 1 to N,`randomNum`, so each line would have a random height, draw the line with the `plot()` helper function (which resides in its own .h file, see below), then append it to the unsorted `lineVector`.

```
sf::RectangleShape plot(int height, int x, int y) { //Returns a single drawn line
    sf::RectangleShape line(sf::Vector2f(height, 1));
    line.setPosition(x, y - height);
    line.rotate(90);
    
    return line;
}
```

My goal is to modify `plot` to insert spaces in between lines on its own, without needing to hard code and update the position of the lines using `xpos`.

`plot` takes three arguments; a `height` representing the length of the line (which when typing this out sounds like it should be changed to length), as well as its `x` and `y` coordinates within the window. Initially, I tried an `int space` variable as a 4th argument that got added to the `x` position as an offset. Additionally, I experimented with a `const int space` variable in the main.cpp, but to no avail.

Comment: Side note: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/events/goingnative-2013/rand-considered-harmful)

Comment: Position of line `i` is `initial_x + i * (line_width + spacing)`, given zero-based indexing.

Comment: Make your loop zero based and pass `xpos + i * 5` to plot in each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to pass the plot function the lineVector, then have it position the new line at lineVector.size() * 5. Or you could just pass it lineVector.size() and have it be position at that times 5....

```
sf::RectangleShape plot(int height, std::vector<sf::RectangleShape> lines, int y) { //Returns a single drawn line
    sf::RectangleShape line(sf::Vector2f(height, 1));
    line.setPosition(lines.size() * 5, y - height);
    line.rotate(90);
    
    return line;
}
```

and then

```
std::vector <sf::RectangleShape> lineVector;

int N;
std::cout << "Enter the size of the vector to be sorted: ";
std::cin >> N;

srand(time(0));

for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    int randomNum = rand() % N + 1;
    sf::RectangleShape line = plot(randomNum, lineVector, 200);
    lineVector.push_back(line);
}
```

to further simplify your code, you could make the plot function automatically add the new line to lineVector...

```
void plot(int height, std::vector<sf::RectangleShape>& lines, int y) { 
    sf::RectangleShape line(sf::Vector2f(height, 1));
    line.setPosition(lines.size() * 5, y - height);
    line.rotate(90);
    
    lines.push_back(line);
}
```

and then...

```
std::vector <sf::RectangleShape> lineVector;

int N;
std::cout << "Enter the size of the vector to be sorted: ";
std::cin >> N;

srand(time(0));

for (int i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
    int randomNum = rand() % N + 1;
    sf::RectangleShape line = plot(randomNum, lineVector, 200);
}
```

Comment: `srand(time(0));` - horrible seeding of a terrible generator.

Comment: `int randomNum = rand() % N + 1;` - You've completely wrecked the average there. See "pigeon hole principle". Why not use a `std::uniform_int_distribution`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl its not my code, let him choose his own random method lmfao